# how to encode one row with auto-encoder in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recommendation-engine, autoencoder

first of all, i downloaded [movielens-100K](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/) which contains u.data (rating matrix) file.

This code simply read this file and create a sparse tensor for it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import SparseTensor
from tensorflow.python.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense

encoding_dim = 40

user_count = 943
movie_count = 1682
rate_count = 100_000

rate_matrix = pd.read_csv('u.data', sep='\t', names=['user id', 'item id', 'rating', 'timestamp'])
rate_matrix_indices = [[x - 1, y - 1] for x, y in rate_matrix[['user id', 'item id']].to_numpy().astype(int)]
rate_matrix_value = rate_matrix['rating'].to_numpy().astype(float)

sparse_rate_tensor = SparseTensor(
    indices=rate_matrix_indices,
    values=rate_matrix_value,
    dense_shape=[user_count, movie_count]
)

rate_tensor = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_rate_tensor, default_value=0, validate_indices=False, name='rate_tensor')
```

After creating `rate_tensor` i simply want to fit an AutoEncoder for first column of it which is the rate's of first movie.

i wrote this code for it:

```
input = Input(shape=(user_count,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, input_dim=(user_count,), activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)(input)
decoded = Dense(user_count, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(encoded)

autoencoder = Model(input, decoded)
autoencoder.summary()

autoencoder.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
    metrics=['accuracy'])

movie_rates = tf.slice(rate_tensor, [0, 0], [user_count, 1])
movie_rates = tf.transpose(movie_rates)

history = autoencoder.fit(movie_rates,
                          movie_rates,
                          steps_per_epoch=1,
                          batch_size=1,
                          epochs=100,
                          shuffle=True)
```

And here is the output:

```
Epoch 98/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: -3.1201 - acc: 0.5270
Epoch 99/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: -3.1274 - acc: 0.5270
Epoch 100/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: -3.1740 - acc: 0.5270
```

After this progress, i tried to do this simple task by my own and i found out it literally learned nothing !!

This is the code:

```
encoder = autoencoder.get_weights()[0]
hidden = np.matmul(movie_rates, encoder)
decoder = autoencoder.get_weights()[2]
output = np.matmul(hidden, decoder)
dif = np.sum(output - movie_rates)
```

And the output is : `1262.012...`

Ok, There are two problems here:

first: Why loss is a negative number? what does it mean? (-3.1740)

second: Why didn't it learn anything from that (943, 1) matrix?

Any Help?

Thanks.

Comment: try decreasing the learning rate

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Ok, i tried with `Adam(lr=0.00001)` and `Adam(lr=0.0001)` form `epochs=800` to `epochs=8000` but still i can not get output from input, and accuracy is about 0.5 which means it rolls a dice for them...